# Keycloak 17.0.1 Import Realm on Docker / Docker-Compose Startup

Tags: docker, docker-compose, keycloak, keycloak-rest-api

I am trying to find a way to import a realm in Keycloak version 17.0.1 that can be done at starting up a docker container (with docker-compose). I want to be able to do this in "start" mode and not "start-dev" mode as in my experience so far "start-dev" in 17 is forcing an H2/in-mem database and not allowing me to point to an external db which I would like to do to more closely resemble dev/prod environments when running locally.

**Things I've tried:**

**1)** It appears that according to recent conversations on Github ([Issue 10216](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/issues/10216) and [Issue 10754](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/pull/10754) to name a couple) that the environment variable that used to allow this (KEYCLOAK_IMPORT or KC_IMPORT_REALM  in some versions) is no longer a trigger for this. In my attempts it also did not work for version 17.0.1.

**2)** I've also tried appending the following command in my docker-compose setup for keycloak and had no luck (also tried with just "start") - It appears to just ignore the command (no error or anything):

`command: ["start-dev", "-Dkeycloak.import=/tmp/my-realm.json"]`

**3)** I tried running the kc.sh command "import" in the Dockerfile (both before and after Entrypoint/start) but got error: Unmatched arguments from index 1: '/opt/keycloak/bin/kc.sh', 'im                                  port', '--file', '/tmp/my-realm.json'

**4)** I've shifted gears and have tried to see if it is possible to just do it after the container starts (even with manual intervention) just to get some sanity restored. I attempted to use the admin-cli but after quite a few different attempts at different points/endpoints etc. I just get that localhost refuses to connect.

`bin/kcadm.sh  config credentials --server http://localhost:8080/auth --realm master --user admin --password adminpassword`

Responds when hitting the following ports as shown:

8080: Failed to send request - Connect to localhost:8080 [localhost/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)

8443: Failed to send request - localhost:8443 failed to respond

I am sure there are other ways that I've tried and am forgetting - I've kind of spun my wheels at this point.

My code (largely the same as the latest docs on the Keycloak website):

Dockerfile:

```
FROM quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:17.0.1 as builder

ENV KC_METRICS_ENABLED=true
ENV KC_FEATURES=token-exchange
ENV KC_DB=postgres
RUN /opt/keycloak/bin/kc.sh build

FROM quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:17.0.1
COPY --from=builder /opt/keycloak/lib/quarkus/ /opt/keycloak/lib/quarkus/
WORKDIR /opt/keycloak
# for demonstration purposes only, please make sure to use proper certificates in production instead
ENV KC_HOSTNAME=localhost
RUN keytool -genkeypair -storepass password -storetype PKCS12 -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -dname "CN=server" -alias server -ext "SAN:c=DNS:localhost,IP:127.0.0.1" -keystore conf/server.keystore

ENTRYPOINT ["/opt/keycloak/bin/kc.sh", "start" ]
```

Docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3"

services:
  keycloak:
    build:
      context: .
    volumes:
      - ./my-realm.json:/tmp/my-realm.json:ro
    env_file:
      - .env
    environment:
      KC_DB_URL: ${POSTGRESQL_URL}
      KC_DB_USERNAME: ${POSTGRESQL_USER}
      KC_DB_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRESQL_PASS}
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN: admin
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD: adminpassword
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
      - 8443:8443 # <-- I've tried with only 8080 and with only 8443 as well. 8443 appears to be the only that I can get the admin console ui to even work on though.
    networks:
      - my_net
networks:
  my_net:
    name: my_net
```

Any suggestion on how to do this in a programmatic + "dev-opsy" way would be greatly appreciated. I'd really like to get this to work but am confused on how to get past this.

Answer (score 4):

Importing realm upon docker initialization thru configuration is not supported yet. See https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/issues/10216. They might release this feature in next release v18.

The workarounds people had shared in github thread is create own docker image and import the realm thru json file when building it.

```
FROM quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:17.0.1

# Make the realm configuration available for import
COPY realm-and-users.json /opt/keycloak_import/

# Import the realm and user
RUN /opt/keycloak/bin/kc.sh import --file /opt/keycloak_import/realm-and-users.json

# The Keycloak server is configured to listen on port 8080
EXPOSE 8080
EXPOSE 8443

# Import the realm on start-up
CMD ["start-dev"]
```

Answer (score 2):

As @tboom said, it was not supported yet by keycloak 17.x. But it is now supported by keycloak 18.x using the `--import-realm` option :

```
bin/kc.[sh|bat] [start|start-dev] --import-realm
```

This feature does not work as it was before. The JSON file path must not be specified anymore: the JSON file only has to be copied in the `<KEYCLOAK_DIR>/data/import` directory (multiple JSON files supported). Note that the import operation is skipped if the realm already exists, so incremental updates are not possible anymore ([at least for the time being](https://keycloak.discourse.group/t/keycloak-17-docker-container-how-to-export-import-realm-import-must-be-done-on-container-startup/13619/10)).

This feature is documented on https://www.keycloak.org/server/importExport#_importing_a_realm_during_startup.